# Which Eclipse Juno Maven Plugin Should I Install

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm trying to build a very simple Java SE project using Hibernate and MySQL and I would like to set up my project using Maven (inside Eclipse Juno). When I search for "Maven" in the marketplace there are 2 options:

- Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP (Incubation)
- Maven Integration for Eclipse

Are there any difference between those two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the first is a component that lets m2e lifecycles work with the wtp process, the second is the actual integration with maven...I would be very surprised if you were you were able to install the first without the second.

imo, skip wtp all together

Comment: Thank you very much for the simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of eclipse version, I believe m2e is the most popular: http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/